# Facebook URL truncated

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a web app which uses [Facebook feed dialog plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) in some pages. When I try to share these pages, the URLs posted to the news feed get truncated.

I'm using the **direct URL approach**. When the user wanna share something, she clicks in a link that is going to redirect her to the feed dialog. The link is composed as shown below:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=MY_APP_ID&link=SHARED_URL&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL`

For example:

**the URL I have in the "link":**`http://www.simplecity.com.br/DP/Index/?CID=0&UID=1`

**the URL I get in the news feed:**`http://www.simplecity.com.br/DP/Index/?CID=0`

Has anyone already experienced this issue? Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the ampersands (`&` -> `&amp;`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cause of this is forgetting to [encode the link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) when you pass it into the Direct FB URL.

Comment: i've had the most success with `encodeURIComponent()`. Confirmed with this method even sending in `http://domain.com/#target` works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to urlencode the `link` parameter (i'm especially thinking of the `&`) when creating the URL you're passing the user to?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem with a straightforward link - I inserted:

https://example.com/page.html

into a page post.  However, on the page it was rendered as:

https://example.com/page.ht...

as if the last two characters of the html extension were merely not displayed, as indicated by the elipsis.  However, if you copy the link from the post you find that those chars are actually missing and the link resolves as 404.  If you edit the post and reinsert the link, it is saved correctly, although the 'overflow' characters are still hidden by the elipsis.  Very misleading.

What seems to work best is if you use the Facebook Developer OG tags in the page and then use Open Graph Debugger to scrape the link.  This puts the URL in the FB realm and it picks up the correct link just fine.  As you are doing this, the debugger tool gives you feedback to the effect: "This is the first time we have seen this URL"; which is baloney if you have put the URL on a FB page beforehand.

I have filed a bug report with Facebook; but I am not expecting them to own up to this bug.