# Url get truncated while posting in facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I am using Facebook like in my web page. The url to be posted is having query string like

```
http://test.something.in:302/sample.aspx?id=54
```

but it is truncated while posted in facebook and the url became

```
http://test.something.in:302/sample.aspx.
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '451971411518111',
        status: true,
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
    });
};
(function (d, debug) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http%3A%2F%2Ftest.something.in%3A302%2Fsample.aspx%3FId%3D54" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post more code? Be more descriptive?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594964/facebook-url-truncated?rq=1

Comment: URL-encoding the URL in the `data-href` value is total nonsense. The only relevant encoding context here is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to encode the link when you pass it to the Facebook Direct FB URL.

A good online encoder can be found at W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

The JavaScript function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp is also good for encoding your URLs on the fly, though I have no clue about what function to use in C# (Don't ask me about C# as I have never coding one character on C#. I don't even know if it has functions. :P)

For example, the URL you provided would be encoded something like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Ftest.something.in%3A302%2Fsample.aspx%3Fid%3D54
```

Tell me if this works.

**BTW this question is basically a duplicate of [Facebook URL truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594964/facebook-url-truncated). Try to avoid duplicates in the future. They can lead to closures of your question, a lot of downvotes (which I was nice enough not to do) and even a temporary ban. Don't worry about it now, just for the future.**